# I cant find the error in my code I always get insufficient funds

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have 3 sql tables set up: 'client' 'inv' and 'wit'
Database connection works fine and other pages in the code, but I'm having issues with this particular page.

I have a page new.php:

```
<?php session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]))
{
    header("location:../login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>
<body>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<form action="withdraw.php" method="post" class="m-form m-form--label-align-right m-form--fit" id="withdrawalForm">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $userVal['email']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="w_date" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y"); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="w_status" value="Pending" />
<input type="hidden" name="balance" value="<?php echo $userVal['balance']; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="method" value="" />
<input type="text" name="balance" value="$<?php echo $userVal['balance']; ?>" disabled=true readonly />
<input type="number" name="w_amount" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $userVal['balance']; ?> or less" required />
<input type="text" name="wallet" value="" placeholder="Wallet Address" required />
<input type="submit" name="withdraw" value="withdraw" />
</body>
</html>
```

The header.php has:

```
<?php
include("pdoconnect.php");

$id = $_SESSION["email"];
$user = $pdotestconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM client JOIN inv ON client.email = inv.email WHERE client.email = :uname ");
$user->bindParam(":uname", $id);
$user->execute();
$userVal = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then I have the withdraw.php:

```
<?php

include("pdoconnect.php");

$datei=date("D M d, Y g:i a"); 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$wdate = $_POST['w_date'];
$method = $_POST['method'];
$wamount = $_POST['w_amount'];
$wstatus = $_POST['w_status'];
$wallet = $_POST['wallet'];

$user = $pdotestconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM client JOIN wit ON client.email = wit.email WHERE client.email = :uname ");
$user->bindParam(":uname", $email);
$user->execute();
$userVal = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($wamount >= $userVal['balance']) {
        echo "Insufficient Fund";
    } else {
        $balance = $userVal['balance'] - $wamount;

        $ins = $pdotestconn->prepare("INSERT INTO wit (email,w_date,method,w_amount,w_status,wallet) VALUES (:email,:w_date,:method,:w_amount,:w_status,:wallet)");
        $ins->bindParam(":email", $email);

        $ins->bindParam(":w_date", $wdate);
        $ins->bindParam(":method", $method);
        $ins->bindParam(":w_amount", $wamount);
        $ins->bindParam(":w_status", $wstatus);
        $ins->bindParam(":wallet", $wallet);
        $ins->execute();

        $up = $pdotestconn->prepare("UPDATE client SET balance = :credit WHERE email = :email ");
        $up->bindParam(":credit", $balance);
        $up->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $up->execute();
        echo "ok";
    }
?>
```

Every time I try to do the withdraw, I get "**Insufficient Funds**" but I have enough funds there.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is doing something unexpected, there's a good chance you're making an assumption somewhere. One thing you can be certain of in your code is that if it's printing "Insufficient Fund" then it sees the value of `$wamount` as greater than or equal to that of `$userVal['balance']`.

This could be because of a couple of reasons, including that the balance isn't as much as you thought, or just as likely, there's some sort of coercion or type difference or incorrect field mapping going on.

My recommendation would be to take a look at those values before the `if` statement. If you have a debugger and know how to use it, do that. But if you don't you could temporarily add this code right before the `if` statement.

```
var_dump('Withdrawal amount', $wamount);
var_dump('Balance', $userVal['balance']);
```

This should result in a bit of output that tells you the values and also the types of the variables `$wamount` and `$userVal['balance']`. Take a look at the values you get. Hopefully the issue will be obvious. If not, pay extra special attention to the types of the variables. If they are different, as in one is a string and the other is a float or an int or something, PHP is doing type coercion and there's possibly something you're not aware of going on with the that which will result in values that seem to be what you expect, but are really not.

Comment: when I tested the var_dump I got **string(17) "Withdrawal amount" string(2) "60" string(7) "Balance" NULL Insufficient Fund** but they are both int in my database (sad-face)

Comment: @littlejamesc Use the query in PHPMyAdmin and see what result you get.

Comment: @littlejamesc well here is something for you that will make you sad-face even more. You just finished only a first iteration in the *endless spiral of debugging*. now you know that  $userVal['balance'] is null you have to find out why. either the value returned is null or the whole row doesn't exist. now it's time to var_dump entire $userVal, and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: if $userVal contains other info but the balance is null then it IS null in your database despite what you think. If $userVal is false, then there is another assumption to check, that $_POST['email'] contain a value that has an exact match in the database. Then you will have to check other assumptions about SQL, database, etc. And yes, debugging takes up most of the programmer's time. Welcome to the club.

Comment: Hi guys, I initially added the balance manually to the sql table. Now I tried setting it in the code: `$userVal['balance'] = 1000`. It worked and updated my sql table with balance - withdraw amount. Then I tried adding in manually again on the sql table, everything worked fine. I still can't say where the initial error of **NULL** was from, but it seems to work fine now. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I put together some test tables to emulate the structure that can be deduced from the above ( it is likely different to your actual db schema ) and worked through the code above to produce the following. This has worked for my tests OK. Note I added the PDO Transaction statements as it seemed appropriate in this situation. One issue I found was the date format used in the hidden field - if the column in the db table is a `date` field then it will likely cause errors hence why I changed the format in the hidden field.

```
mysql> describe client;
+---------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email   | varchar(64)            | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| balance | decimal(10,2) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe wit;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email    | varchar(64)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| w_date   | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| method   | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| w_amount | decimal(10,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| w_status | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| wallet   | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe inv;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email | varchar(64)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The script is all on one page for testing:

```
<?php

    $error=false;
    $message=false;

    $dbport =   3306;
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root';
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
    $dbname =   'xxx';

    $options=array( 
        PDO::ATTR_CURSOR                    =>  PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT                =>  false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY  =>  true,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES          =>  true,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND        =>  'SET NAMES \'utf8mb4\' COLLATE \'utf8mb4_general_ci\', @@sql_mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES, @@foreign_key_checks = 1'
    );
    $dsn='mysql:host='.$dbhost.';port='.$dbport.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8';
    $db=new PDO( $dsn, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $options );







    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['email'],$_POST['w_date'],$_POST['method'],$_POST['w_amount'],$_POST['w_status'],$_POST['wallet'] ) ){
        #$datei=date("D M d, Y g:i a"); /* unused */
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $wdate = $_POST['w_date'];
        $method = $_POST['method'];
        $wamount = $_POST['w_amount'];
        $wstatus = $_POST['w_status'];
        $wallet = $_POST['wallet'];


        /* seems like an appropriate candidate for a `Transaction` !! */
        $db->beginTransaction();



        $sql='select * from `client` join `wit` on client.email = wit.email where client.email = :uname';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        $args=array(
            ':uname' => $email
        );
        $stmt->execute( $args );
        $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );



        $balance = floatval( $rs->balance ) - floatval( $wamount );



        if( $balance < 0 ){

            /* Cannot withdraw more than is in the account - error */
            $db->rollback();
            $error='Error: Insufficient funds!';

        } else {
            $status=false;



            $sql='insert into `wit` ( `email`, `w_date`, `method`, `w_amount`, `w_status`, `wallet` ) values ( :email, :date, :method, :amount, :status, :wallet )';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $args=array(
                ':email'    =>  $email,
                ':date'     =>  $wdate,
                ':method'   =>  $method,
                ':amount'   =>  $wamount,
                ':status'   =>  $wstatus,
                ':wallet'   =>  $wallet
            );
            $res=$stmt->execute( $args );





            if( $res ){
                $sql='update `client` set `balance`=:balance where `email`=:email';
                $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                $args=array(
                    ':balance'  =>  $balance,
                    ':email'    =>  $email
                );
                $status=$stmt->execute( $args );
            }

            if( $status ){
                $db->commit();
                $message=sprintf('Congratulations! You have successfully transferred %s', floatval( $wamount ) );
            } else {
                $message=sprintf('Sorry, there was a problem transferring %s', floatval( $wamount ) );
            }
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Money money money</title>
        <style>
            .error{color:red}
            .status{color:green}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

        /* to emulate header.php */
        $sql='select * from `client` join inv on client.email = inv.email where client.email = :uname';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

        /* Rather than a session, to test a statically declared email will suffice */
        $id='client@example.com';

        /* In practice you will use $_SESSION['email'] here */

        $args=array(
            ':uname' => $id
        );
        $res=$stmt->execute( $args );
        $userVal=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOTH );

    ?>



        <form method='post'><!-- POST to same page for testing -->
            <?php

                if( $error )printf( '<h1 class="error">%s</h1>', $error );
                if( $message )printf( '<h1 class="status">%s</h1>', $message );

            ?>

            <input type='hidden' name='email' value='<?php echo $userVal['email']; ?>' />
            <input type='hidden' name='w_date' value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>' /><!-- incorrect date format for DB -->
            <input type='hidden' name='w_status' value='Pending' />
            <input type='hidden' name='balance' value='<?php echo $userVal['balance']; ?>' />


            <input type='text' name='method' value='' placeholder='Method' />
            <input type='text' name='balance' value='$<?php echo $userVal['balance']; ?>' disabled=true readonly />
            <input type='number' name='w_amount' value='' placeholder='<?php echo $userVal['balance']; ?> or less' required />
            <input type='text' name='wallet' value='' placeholder='Wallet Address' required />

            <input type='submit' name='withdraw' value='Withdraw' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```