# My function returns true when I expect false

Tags: php, function, pdo, return, boolean

I am confused as to why my code returns `true` when I expect `false` and the other way around. Here's my code:

```
public function CheckMac($mac){
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->connectDatabase();
    $checkedmac = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `displays` WHERE `displayMac` = '$mac'");
    $checkedmac->execute();
    $count = (int)$checkedmac->fetchColumn();
    if ($count > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the query right, when I echo `$mac`and put it inside the query, phpMyAdmin gives me back the expected line, since it exists in the database, but when I run this code, I'm getting a `false` return.

Where did I go wrong on this one?

Comment: Enable error reporting/check logs.

Comment: What result you are expecting from query? Do you want count of number of records available in table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fantastic yet underestimated answer, [If your code is doing something unexpected, there's a good chance you're making an assumption somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58230223/285587).

You are yet to learn the cornerstone concept in the art of programming called *debugging*. Which means *you are supposed to verify every single assumption you made*.

You are assuming here that when a query returns a row, the `(int)$checkedmac->fetchColumn();` statement returns a positive number. So you have to verify it.

I can make an *assumption* that the first column in your table does not contain a positive number but rather a string. A string cast a number will return 0. It will explain why you're getting 0 when a record is found. But you have to verify it as well.

If my assumption proves to be true, simply select a constant value instead of rather uncertain `*`. You can use `1` for example, and your query will work flawlessly:

```
public function CheckMac($db, $mac){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM `displays` WHERE `displayMac` = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$mac]);
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

A couple notes:

- you should always connect only **once**. Create a $db variable beforehand in a single place and then use it everywhere
- you are using a [cargo cult prepared statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement) that protects from nothing. It should be always the way shown in my example.
- `if ($count > 0) return true` is a *tautology*. A `$count > 0` statement already returns `true` or `false`, so you can return its result rigtht away, without a superfluous condition
- moreover, 1 is as good as true in PHP. So in the end you can return the result of fetchColumn() right away. in case the row is found it will be 1 equal to true and just false otherwise.

Comment: It all works now, and you made my code a bit better, Thanks for your help sir

Comment: The explanation was great!